# Spring and problem with data

Tags: java, spring, curl

I have a problem with data. I have a class where I have setters and getters. Using curl I need to show data and others things. I am using jetty server. This is code from my class which I use to get data:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
public Date getDate() {

    return date;
}


@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

and this is results: [image]

This is what I get in console:
[{"createdAt":1308649398723,"period":0,"date":1308649398723,"updatedAt":null,"id":null}]

I would like to know how I can change data format on YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS. 
I add :

```
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DateTimeFormat {

    String style() default "SS";

    org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat.ISO iso() ;

    String pattern() default "";

    public enum ISO {

        DATE,

        TIME,

        DATE_TIME,

        NONE

    }
}
```

and change

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME,,pattern="M/d/yy h:mm a")
public Date getDate() {

    return date;
}


@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME,,pattern="M/d/yy h:mm a")
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

and still not working

Comment: That image is too small to be readable - just cut and paste the text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [`pattern`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html#pattern%28%29) in the `DateTimeFormat` annotation, instead of the `iso` attribute.